# Error Running Application on Emulator and Device in OS version 4.0.3

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator

I am working on an android application and recently I have updated the Android SDK. I am developing in Eclipse Indigo version 3.7.1. I have in my app manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk       
    android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

And it runs absolutely fine for the later OS versions. But when i try to run it on OS version 4.0.3 i get the following error. Which i am unaware of. Can someone elaborate this error that why is it so and what is the solution for this.

Following is the error:

```
[2012-01-06 17:08:21 - my-app] Failed to install my-app.apk on device 'emulator-5556':    EOF
[2012-01-06 17:08:21 - my-app] java.io.IOException: EOF
[2012-01-06 17:08:21 - my-app] Launch canceled!
```

Any help is appreciated...!!!

Comment: No it's not working ... i don't know why...and no doubt it generally does solve the problem.